# Number of combinations with repeats

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $m$ digit number of base $n$ where repeats are allowed. How do I find the number of combinations?  I came across this trying to find the number of nonisomorphic graphs of order $m$.

Examples:

For a 2 digit number of base 2:

$00, 01, 11$

For a 3 digit number of base 4:

$000, 001, 002, 003, 011, 012, 013, 022, 023, 033, 111, 112, 113, 122, 123, 133, 222, 223, 233, 333$

Comment: I have a feeling finding the number of nonisomorphic graphs of order $k$ is a much harder problem than finding the number of $n$-digit base-$m$ numbers, and I'm not sure where the $k$ came from.

Comment: @genisage I agree, I fixed the $k$.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. I thought you were trying to solve this problem by counting nonisomorphic graphs. The number of ways to pick a string of length $m$ from an alphabet of size $n$ has a very simple formula, $n^m$. Good luck with your graphs.

Comment: @genisage Yes, but I need strings that do not have the same combination of letters. Combinations may not be the right word, see my two examples.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that. You're looking for multisets. $n$ multiset $m$ is $m+n-1 \choose m$